# Python While Loops Asterisk

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

Re-type and run, note incorrect behavior. Then fix errors in the code, which should print num_stars asterisks.

```
while num_printed != num_stars:
    print('*')
```

Below is the code which I have entered. I am getting an infinite loop hence no answer. Please help me out! Thanks!

```
num_stars = 3

num_printed = 0

while(num_printed != num_stars):

    print(num_stars*'*')
```

Comment: You're never incrementing num_printed. Also, don't check `!=`, check `>` for greater check safety.

Comment: `print(num_stars*'*')` prints num_stars asterisks. There is no need for the `while` loop.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming

Comment: Sean Pianka: is this what you meant? 

num_stars = 3
num_printed = 0

while(num_printed > num_stars):
    print(num_stars * '*')
Program isnt producing an output.

Comment: zvone: I have to use a while loop because 3 is not the only value of num_stars which is being checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want either:

```
num_stars = 3
print(num_stars * '*')
```

or:

```
num_stars = 3
num_printed = 0
while(num_printed < num_stars):
    print('*')
    num_printed += 1
```

Depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: It may be worth to emphasize that these two code snippets are not equivalent.

Comment: Thanks! it was the second one which I needed!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the original question which the OP was asking about, is badly worded.

---

The original question was:

"Retype or copy, and then run the following code; note incorrect behavior. Then fix errors in the code, which should print num_stars asterisks."

````
```while num_printed != num_stars:
print('*')
```
````

Sample output with input: 3

*

*

*

---

The question is better understood if it is reworded to say:

Correct this Python code, so that when the Python code is run, it will print asterisks until the amount of asterisks printed matches the number you entered.

The first part of the code is already prewritten and some lines can't be modified.

```
num_printed = 0

num_stars = int(input())

''' Your solution goes here '''
```

My solution was similar to what the others posted.

```
num_printed = 0

num_stars = int(input())

while (num_printed < num_stars):
    print('*')
    num_printed += 1
```

I added "How many asterisks do you want to print? " for my own sanity, to "input()". It helped keep me on track while I was figuring out the "while" statement on line 5.

Answer (score -1):

Retype or copy, and then run the following code; note incorrect behavior. Then fix errors in the code, which should print num_stars asterisks.

```
num_printed = 0

num_stars = int(input())

''' Your solution goes here '''
while (num_printed < num_stars):
   print('*')
   num_printed += 1
```